# Why does declaring an `operator bool() const` member overload the [] operator?

Tags: c++, operators

Why does this code compile? Since no `operator[]` is declared, I'd expect it to fail. Where is the `operator[]` definition coming from?

```cpp
struct Test {
    operator bool() const {
        return true;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Test test;

    if (test["wut"])
        cout << "Success (test[\"wut\"])\n";
}
```

Comment: Those other questions may have the same answer, but they are definitely not the same question or else I would have found them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator is coming from the [built-in subscript operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_subscript_operator) which treats expressions `A[B]` as `*(A + B)`.

In these cases, `test` is being implicitly converted to an integer type of value `0` or `1` through the `operator bool()` method (`1` for all of these cases).

This results in the evaluation of `*(1 + "wut")` => `'u'`, which then causes the `if` condition to pass, as `'u'` is a non-zero value. Likewise, the following condition would also pass `if ("wut"[test])` as this resolves to `"wut"[1]` => `*("wut" + 1)` => `*("ut")` => `'u'`

Declare your member as `explicit operator bool()` to prevent your type from being implicitly converted to other integral types.